# Posting to web api

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

What would be the best or better way to handle posting to a web api and how would it be done via C#?

Web API code

```
public class ProcessController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "Hello from API";
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult ApiPost(Model m)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Code to call web api

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2478/api/Process/");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("test");

Model m = new Model ();
m.Id= 4;
m.Name = "test";

var r = client.PostAsJsonAsync("ApiPost", m);
```

This returns a 500 internal server error. Is there something missing here?

Web API config

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var settings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete sample of your Web API.  A 500 error indicates a server-side error, but we can only guess.

Comment: @Amy that's really it. I'm just trying to get a post through. I was able to do it with a single string parameter but I can't successfully post with a object. There's no other code in the post method as of right now.

Comment: There is absolutely more code you can provide.  Include the controller.  Include your global.asax.  You are doing something server side, and we cannot guess what.  Have you launched your web api in a debugger to see where the fault is?  We cannot answer this without a [mcve].

Comment: It seems to me that the route you are specifing is incorrect, but that would not match with the status code that you are reporting. Can you share the routes configuration that is on your App_Start Configuration file ? instead of http://localhost:2478/api/Process/ try http://localhost:2478/Process/ as your base address and see if the status code starts to be on the 400 range.

Comment: @VitorPaulino the same address works if I do a get request. Just seems to fail on the post locally.

Comment: @VitorPaulino the issue was my routing. I was able to fix it after I added the action in the routing.  It looks like my code didn't know what action to call.

Comment: @Amy you were right. Posting more of that code would of revealed the issue. Having 2 post methods without specifying the routing for the action created an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this: add the FromBody attribute to your model and post a model that matches m in the body

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ApiPost([FromBody] Model m)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I did try this. The issue turned out to be the routing that was configured for the web api.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the routing code to include the action fixed the issue. It looks like the code to call the web API worked fine so long as their was one GET or POST method as any call would try to use one of those.

Without the action it did not know which method to use in the API controller as it could not route to it.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```